# please correct me with the sql query

Tags: sql

Whats wrong wrong with this query please correct me on this  syntactcally it's going wrong please correct me on this how to concatenate this

```
string cmd = "SELECT * 
                FROM [tbl_students] 
               WHERE course_id=@courseId 
                 AND branch_id IN ("+branchId+") 
                 AND (@passoutYear is null or passout_year>=@passoutYear) 
                 AND (@currentBacklog is null or current_backlog<=@currentBacklog)
                 AND gender=@sex 
                 AND (@eGap is null or gapin_education<=@egap)
                 AND (@firstYrPercent is null or first_yea_percent>=@firstYrPercent
                 AND (@secondYrpercent is null or second_year_percent>=@secondYrPercent)
                 AND (@thirdYrPercent is null or third_year_percent>=@thirdYrPercent)
                 AND (@finalYrpercent is null or final_year_percent>=@finalYrpercent)
                 AND (@currentDegreePercentage is null current_degree_percent>=@currentDegreePercentage)
                 AND (@highSchoolPercentage is null high_school_percentage>=@highSchoolPercentage)
                 AND (@higherSchoolPercentage is null higher_school_percentage>=@higherSchoolPercentage)
                 AND (@graduationPercent is null graduation_percent>=@graduationPercentage)
                 AND (@diplomaPercentage is null diploma_percentage>=@diplomaPercenage)
                 AND (@noOfAtkt is null or no_of_atkt<=@noOfAtkt)
                 AND (@date is null or date_of_birth>=@date)";
```

Comment: What is the exact error being given? What does `branchId` contain (write `cmd` to the output stream and see what is printed)?

Comment: branchId is string builder object . there is problem in concatenation 
when i remove that branchId it correct the syntax problem

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error message and the name and version of the database you're using? (Looks like Microsoft SQL Server)

Comment: what programming language are you using (to run the query)?

Comment: the format is exact as mentioned above i havn't run it yet so i can't commit the error but while after typing it i see the red lines belove the all line except first line.
when i take cursor belove the null red spot area it says (type expected) and for @variable it says (; expected) and for (IN("+branchId+") it says newLine is constant please correct me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

Are you getting an error while trying to COMPILE the code, as opposed to running the SQL query?

I'm going to bet that you're using C#, and that you should do multi-line strings with an @-symbol before the "-symbol. Such as this:

```
string blabla = @"
     hello
     there
";
```

Then of course you need it also when you open up the string after `branchId`

Comment: you are apsolutely correct my dear friend u made it clear
i did the same explained by you above and it work.

But can you elaborate a bit on this y i have to do this, i mean i want you to tell me regarding concatenation on it

Comment: I am honestly not sure why they designed it that way. I think it makes sense though, that a normal string never carry text that is natural to the text editor. It seems like a good principle, for special characters to be denoted by a sequence of characters, like \n. Then I suppose they offered this as a short hand of some sort.

Comment: on running y is it giving error
 Must declare the scalar variable "@courseId"

Answer (score 2):

First, if `branchId` is a string, then you'll need these single quotes:

```
branch_id IN('"+branchId+"') AND
```

though I don't understand why it's not parameterized like so:

```
branch_id = @branchId AND
```

Second, you may have misspelled the word 'year' in this field name:

```
AND  (@firstYrPercent is null or first_year_percent>=@firstYrPercent
```

Finally, you're missing a few OR's here:

```
AND  (@currentDegreePercentage is null OR current_degree_percent>=@currentDegreePercentage)
AND  (@highSchoolPercentage is null OR high_school_percentage>=@highSchoolPercentage)
AND  (@higherSchoolPercentage is null OR higher_school_percentage>=@higherSchoolPercentage)
AND  (@graduationPercent is null OR graduation_percent>=@graduationPercentage)
AND  (@diplomaPercentage is null OR diploma_percentage>=@diplomaPercenage)
```

Comment: branchId an object od string builder having integer values that's y
correct me if i am wrong somewhere

Comment: What's the value of `branchId`'s string representation?

Comment: on running y is it giving error Must declare the scalar variable "@courseId"