# sql query error

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [please correct me with the sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499381/please-correct-me-with-the-sql-query)

giving error mentioned below y so please correct me on this

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@courseId".

```
@"SELECT * FROM [tbl_students] WHERE course_id=@courseId AND branch_id IN("+branchId+@") 
                AND (@passoutYear is null OR passing_year>=@passoutYear) 
               AND  (@currentBacklog is null OR current_backlog<=@currentBacklog)
AND  gender=@sex AND (@eGap is null OR gapin_education<=@egap)
AND  (@firstYrPercent is null OR first_year_percent>=@firstYrPercent
AND  (@secondYrpercent is null OR second_year_percent>=@secondYrPercent)
AND  (@thirdYrPercent is null OR third_year_percent>=@thirdYrPercent)
AND  (@finalYrpercent is null OR final_year_percent>=@finalYrpercent)
AND  (@currentDegreePercentage is null OR current_degree_percent>=@currentDegreePercentage)
AND  (@highSchoolPercentage is null OR highschool_percentage>=@highSchoolPercentage)
AND  (@higherSchoolPercentage is null OR ssc_percentage>=@higherSchoolPercentage)
AND  (@graduationPercent is null OR graduation_percentage>=@graduationPercentage)
AND  (@diplomaPercentage is null OR diploma_percentage>=@diplomaPercenage)
AND  (@noOfAtkt is null OR number_of_ATKT<=@noOfAtkt)
AND  (@date is null OR DOB>=@date)"
```

Comment: Please edit your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499381/please-correct-me-with-the-sql-query) instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @BoltClock: the original question (3499381) appears to have been due to an error caused by omitting an @ symbol from before the start of the query string - see Helgi Hrafn Gunnarsson's answer, which was accepted as correct. This question concerns an error in the SQL itself; I therefore think it was a mistake to close it as a duplicate of the original question. I don't know how to do it, but I recommend re-opening this question.

Comment: Please can you respond to some of the answers that have already been left to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have either:

- Not declared your variable `@courseId` within the SQL query
- Not declared a parameter to the Stored Procedure

Answer (score -1):

That just means you forgot to create an `SqlParameter` value for `@courseId` for your command.